# Getting "Label" tags work in Internet Explorer 6 (for radio buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*Problem:*
Label tags don't work as they should, clicking on Label didn't uncheck radio buttons.
This works in Mozilla Firefox but I am unable to get it work in Internet Explorer 6. Is there any javascript/jquery workaround.

```
<p>Would you prefer to walk without effort?</p>
<input type="radio" value="a" name="radgrp2"/> Yes <br />
<input type="radio" value="b" name="radgrp2"/> No <br /> 
<input type="radio" value="c" name="radgrp2"id="rad[1]" style="display:none;"/>
<label for="rad[1]"><input type ="button"value="Clear"/></label>
```

Thanks...

Comment: [Poor soul dealing with a dead browser.](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/ie6countdown) Is there really no space between the id and the name? If you remove the button, does it work?

Comment: @epascarello Yes after removing Label, it works. However I need to make it work with Label.

Comment: Can I ask why you're writing something for IE6?  It's been obsolete for 7 years and will no longer be supported by Microsoft as of April 2014... It's time to move on I think.

Comment: @howard many people in my country still use IE6, thats why I have to support it.

Comment: I understand, it's just terrible that us as developers are expected to support such obsolete software.  Why do you have to use the label tag?  The only thing that I can think would to do a browser detect, and then write a work-around for IE6-7.  I think the actual problem may be the "for" attribute, not the "label" tag itself.

Comment: Why don't you style the label to look like a button? Other option would be to add an onclick handler to the button and click the label.

Comment: @howard I used label tag because I needed to hide the third radio button.Is there any alternative to for attribute.

Comment: @epascarello I will try that. but I'm tired now. :D

Comment: You could avoid creating the problem in the first place: just use a visible radio button (to denote “no answer”). Better usability and accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple jQuery fix that hides any inputs that are children of a label tag:

```
        <p>Would you prefer to walk without effort?</p>
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="radgrp2"/> Yes <br />
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="radgrp2"/> No <br /> 
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="radgrp2" id="rad[1]" style="display:none;"/>
        <label for="rad[1]"><input type="button"value="Clear"/></label>

        <script>
            $("label>input").hide();
        </script>
```

Try it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/VA3EH/1/

This is really easy to reverse as well, by calling show() on the element.

Here is a nice, dynamic way to do this:

```
        <p>Would you prefer to walk without effort?</p>
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="radgrp2"/> Yes <br />
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="radgrp2"/> No <br /> 
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="radgrp2" id="rad[1]" style="display:none;"/>
        <label for="rad[1]"><input type="button"value="Clear"/></label>

        <script>
            $("label>input").hide();
            $("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
                $(this).nextAll("label").find("input").show();
            })
        </script>
```

The button is hidden, until a radio button is clicked.  Once the radio button is clicked, then the clear button shows.  Try it out:  http://jsfiddle.net/25z3h/

Then, if you really want to get fancy, attach another event handler to the button, to clear the checkbox values, and hide itself again:

```
        <p>Would you prefer to walk without effort?</p>
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="radgrp2"/> Yes <br />
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="radgrp2"/> No <br /> 
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="radgrp2" id="rad[1]" style="display:none;"/>
        <label for="rad[1]"><input type="button"value="Clear"/></label>

        <script>
            $("label>input").hide();
            $("input[type='radio']").click(function () {
                $(this).nextAll("label").find("input").show();
                $(this).nextAll("label").find("input").click(function () {
                    $(this).parent("label").prevAll("input[type='radio']").removeAttr("checked");
                    $(this).hide();
                })
            })
        </script>
```

Try it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/VA3EH/2/

Comment: Thanks it works, but how to retain value= "c" show that it can be passed to another function. Every element that is cleared should have value "c".

Comment: The radio button keeps the assigned value, it's just hidden not removed from the DOM.  You can then use this value anywhere else you need it.  **Please mark this answer as accepted if this it works well for you and you're pleased with the results**

Comment: but it doesn't retain value in my case with IE6, may be I am doing something wrong. is there a option to force value "c" to the radio group, if clear is clicked.

Comment: Ok - when the form is submitted, the fields that have display:none may not submit to the server in IE6.  On your submit button action, have it show all of the elements first, like $("input").show(); then submit it

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is to use just a JavaScript-driven button that checks the hidden radio button. Replace the `label` element by the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick=
"document.getElementById('rad[1]').checked = true" />
```

The downside is that this won’t work when JavaScript is disabled. For unobtrusive JavaScript, you should generate this `input` element with JavaScript.

Note that your current code violates HTML rules, both [HTML 4 rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL)s and [HTML5 CR rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element). You are associating the `label` with two elements (one via `for`, one via nesting), which is forbidden. So the code should not be expected to work at all.

The best approach is to make the “no selection” alternative a normal radio button with a normal label. This works across all browsers and requires no JavaScript:

```
<input type="radio" value="c" name="radgrp2" id="rad[1]" />
<label for="rad[1]">No preference</label>
```

Comment: it works, how to assign value= "c" to it. and I have 10 such divs in each page.

Comment: @user3003299, assign it to *what*? The code in your question already has `value="c"`, so what is the problem with that?

Comment: I am not sure but something is wrong. when I click submit button the value passed is not "c" but something else.

Comment: Since 'Label for' does not work in IE6, clicking on the button labelled for radio button doesn't actually sets the value = "c" for the radio group, I guess.

Comment: @user3003299, you are still not saying what does not work. If you apply the solution that I propose as the best approach, what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: When I click on label tag it doesn't dis-select other options in the group of radio buttons. (Internet Explorer 6)

Comment: What is the actual markup you are using? Please test my prefereed answer and specify exactly what does not work there. It surely works when I test it on any version of IE.

Comment: Oh yes, it worked actually I missed javascript you posted earlier in your post now I could see it. But I have approx 10 questions in every chapter, will I have to mention the same code evrey time or can I call a function, which would be faster and better... :D